# JavaFx TableView SQLException query does not return results

Tags: sqlite, javafx, tableview, scenebuilder, sqlexception

I am trying to build simple School Managment System in JavaFX with SceneBuilder and SQLlite. I have previously created similar App in Swing and it went good without any Exceptions.
I set up my database to be displayed in a TableView
When I want to add new data 'Student' into database the code is executed and after i get exception, **SQLException Query does not return results**, the problem is, code is executed and student is added to database, so i don't understand why I get this error, i try few different ways but it don't work.

```
@FXML public void addStudentData(ActionEvent action) throws SQLException 
{

    con = ConnectionDB.connect();
    String id = idbox.getText();
     String name = namebox.getText();
     String sname = snamebox.getText();
     String dob = dobbox.getText();
     String eng = engbox.getText();
     String math = mathbox.getText();
     String sc = sciencebox.getText();
     String art = artbox.getText();
     String pe = pebox.getText();
     String drama = dramabox.getText();
     String geo = geobox.getText();
     String it = itbox.getText();
    String rd = rdbox.getText();

    String sqlp = "INSERT INTO DETAILS (ID,name,SecondName,BirthDate,ENG,MATHS,SC,ART,PE,DRAMA,GEO,IT,RD) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";



    PreparedStatement pr = null;}
try {
    pr = con.prepareStatement(sqlp);



        pr.setString(1, id);
        pr.setString(2, name);
        pr.setString(3, sname);
        pr.setString(4, dob);
        pr.setString(5, eng);
        pr.setString(6, math);
        pr.setString(7, sc);
        pr.setString(8, art);
        pr.setString(9, pe);
        pr.setString(10, drama);
        pr.setString(11, geo);
        pr.setString(12, it);
        pr.setString(13, rd);

        ResultSet rs1 = pr.executeQuery();



}

catch (SQLException e) {}
finally {pr.execute();pr.close();}}
```

I believe the error is here, i checked the tables and names, I try to change PreparedStatement to Statement and executeQuery to executeUpdate, this didn't work either.

[When I click on add Student I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/978VW.png)

[But Student still is added to database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcgpE.png)

It doesn't seem like a very big issue because code is executed and data added to database but it should't be like this.

Comment: `sqlp` isn't even used. I don't see your code doing anything meaningful.

Comment: I don't know why try block is missing here.. i will fix it asap

Comment: `executeQuery` only works for SQL that returns results. Any SQL that modifies the db needs to be run using `executeUpdate`.

Comment: Works now, my silly mistake, i had line to execute statement in finally and try block. I've deleted execute from finally